# Bad math environment delimiter while mixing math and tikz

Tags: latex, figure, tikz

The code below

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \begin{document}
            \[ X = 
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \matrix[matrix of math nodes,left delimiter = (,right delimiter = ),row sep=10pt,column sep = 10pt] (m)
            {
                1&3&-8 \\
                2&0&1 \\
                -7&9&1 \\
            };
            \end{tikzpicture}
            \]
    \end{document}
```

Generates "*Bad math environment delimiter. ]*" error. I'm including the above code as a figure in another tex file. If I use $$ instead of [], it compiles but "*X*" will be inlined and not centred with matrix. How can I fix this issue?

*** I have included tikz in the master file.

Answer (score 1):

The error you get comes frome the standalone document class, you can learn more [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50162/how-to-make-a-standalone-document-with-one-equation)

A workaround I suggest in your case is writing the X also with `TikZ`, here is how I do it :

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
    \begin{document}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node (matrix) [matrix of math nodes,
                left delimiter = (,right delimiter = ),
                row sep=10pt,
                column sep = 10pt] {
                    1   &   3   &   -8 \\
                    2   &   0   &   1 \\
                    -7  &   9   &   1 \\
                };
                \node [left=3mm of matrix] {$X=$};
            \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

to get : [image: resulting matrix]